# Unity Steering behaviours and Behaviour Trees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, behavior-tree

I’m trying to implement AI system in unity using steering behaviours and Behaviour Trees as part of a project.
I have most steering behaviour that work properly and the Behaviour tree as well but currently they are seperated.
My agent behaviour tree, what it does currently, is move to a enemy location and perform some attacks. However I wanted to create a new class inside of the Agent BT to make the agent wander before finding the enemy and engaging in combat. However I’m not sure what’s the best approuch to call the Wander script inside of the agent BT and execute it.

This is one of the classes inside of the Agent BT that handles the movement towards the enemy

```
public class AgentMoveToEnemy : BTNode
{
    private AgentBB aBB;
    private Agent agentRef;
    bool firstRun = true;

    public AgentMoveToEnemy(Blackboard bb, Agent agent) : base(bb)
    {
        aBB = (AgentBB)bb;
        agentRef = agent;
    }

    public override BTStatus Execute()
    {
        if (firstRun)
        {
            firstRun = false;
            Debug.Log("Moving to enemy");
        }
        BTStatus rv = BTStatus.RUNNING;
        if ((agentRef.transform.position - aBB.enemyLocation).magnitude <= 10.0f)
        {
            agentRef.AgentMoveTo(aBB.enemyLocation);

        }

        if ((agentRef.transform.position - aBB.enemyLocation).magnitude <= 1.0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("Reached the enemy");
            rv = BTStatus.SUCCESS;
            firstRun = true;
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

And this is my wander behaviour

```
public class Wander : Steering
{
    [SerializeField] private float wanderRate = 0.4f;
    [SerializeField] private float wanderOffset = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float wanderRadius = 4f;

    private float wanderOrientation = 0f;

    private float RandomBinomial()
    {
        return Random.value - Random.value;
    }

    private Vector3 OrientationToVector(float orientation)
    {
        return new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(orientation), 0, Mathf.Sin(orientation));
    }

    public override SteeringData GetSteering(SteeringBehaviours steeringBehaviours)
    {
        SteeringData steering = new SteeringData();
        wanderOrientation += RandomBinomial() * wanderRate;

        float characterOrientation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        float targetOrientation = wanderOrientation + characterOrientation;

        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position + (wanderOffset * OrientationToVector(characterOrientation));
        targetPosition += wanderRadius * OrientationToVector(targetOrientation);

        steering.linear = targetPosition - transform.position;
        steering.linear.Normalize();
        steering.linear *= steeringBehaviours.maxAcceleration;
        

        return steering;
    }
}
```

I tried to get the Wander behaviour through: `agentRef.AddComponent<Wander>` however only adds the component it doesn't actually do anything else even when I use the steering Behaviour script that handles the steering forces,

Can someone help me?

Comment: It would probably help to know the rest of the types (such as Steering, BtNode etc) or at least which asset/package/library these are from

Comment: @derHugo the Steering is just an abstract class that connects to Steering Behaviours Class, that, as I mentioned, just handles the forces.
for the beaviour tree is more complex. the BTNode is part of the script Node that basically is the foundation for any behaviour tree, contains the logic for selectors, sequence, decorators, etc.
The class AgentMoveToEnemy is the behaviour tree created for a specific Agent. Gave that class as example because what I need is something identical but, instead of the Agent moving to the Enemy, I want it to Wander by calling the wander script.

Comment: Surely you add the node to the left of find enemy with a success of wander only succeeds when it has found enemy